# Azure Search: Indexing plain text inside ZIP archive

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am trying to index plain text files inside several zipped archives hosted on Azure Files in Azure Search, but I am hitting all sorts of issues and the documentation is quite limited on indexing contents in a ZIP archives.

- The zip files are indexed, however I am not able to "crack open" the archives to index the text files inside; the content field tries to hold the entire zip file. Does the content field need to be changed to a "complex type"?
- I tried for testing to remove the "content" index field and now hit a limitation "Document is '27789211' bytes, which exceeds the maximum size '16777216' bytes for document extraction for your current service tier. To ignore this error and continue indexing storage metadata of oversized blobs, set the 'indexStorageMetadataOnlyForOversizedDocuments' configuration parameter to true." - Azure Search SKU is Basic

Index:

```
    {
      "name" : "zipindex",
      "fields": [
          { "name": "ID", "type": "Edm.String", "key": true, "searchable": false },
          { "name": "metadata_storage_name", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": false, "filterable": true, "sortable": true  },
          { "name": "metadata_storage_path", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": false, "filterable": true, "sortable": true },
          { "name": "metadata_storage_size", "type": "Edm.Int64", "searchable": false, "filterable": true, "sortable": true  },
          { "name": "metadata_storage_content_type", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": true }     
      ]
    }
```

Indexer:

```
    {
      "name" : "zipindexer",
      "dataSourceName" : "datasource",
      "targetIndexName" : "zipindex",
      "parameters": {
         "batchSize": null,
         "maxFailedItems": null,
         "maxFailedItemsPerBatch": null,
         "base64EncodeKeys": null,
         "configuration": {
            "indexedFileNameExtensions" : ".zip,.txt,.ini,.vzg",
            "excludedFileNameExtensions" : ".png,.jpeg,.dat,.img"
        }
      },
      "schedule" : { },
      "fieldMappings" : [ ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're in fact exceeding the limits of a field length in your index. If that is the case, there's nothing you can do besides chunking the large text file into smaller ones.